# Excel Print command, creating text template

Tags: templates, excel, text, export, vba

Hi I am new to VBA and was looking to output my Excel sheet data into a text template. So far all I have been able to do is output the data but I don't know where to go from there. What I have:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim myFile As String, rng As Range, cellValue As Variant, i As Integer, j As Integer
myFile = "C:\Users\Francis\Desktop\redirect.txt"
Set rng = Selection
Open myFile For Output As #1

For i = 1 To rng.Rows.Count
    For j = 1 To rng.Columns.Count
    cellValue = rng.Cells(i, j).Value

If j = rng.Columns.Count Then
    Print #1, cellValue
Else
    Print #1, cellValue,
End If
    Next j
Next i
Close #1
End Sub
```

I wish to change this so the text output isn't just  "celldataA*" "celldataB*" etc.
I want to make it so that the document starts with 
`<rule>` and ends with `</rule>`
Then each row would come out as

```
  <rule name="Rule rownumber*" patternSyntax="ExactMatch" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="celldataA*" />
    <action type="Redirect" url="celldataB*" />
  </rule>
```

Any pointers? It's that or I manually do it myself 3.5k times so any help at all is welcome.

Comment: so this looks like you want to output xml according to a custom schema - is that right?

Comment: Do you only need the above XML, as in it's the same every single time? Just create a string with the values and concatenate with the cell data? Or is this much more complex?

Comment: Yeah! that is it.   To start the text file with the text `<rules>` and end it with `</rules>` then just have the rownumber* columnA*, and columnB* pulled into the text as stated above and repeat for each row.  No idea how to do this though.

Answer (score 0):

These resources on generating XML from Excel should help you.

- [MS Office.Com: Create an XML data file and XML schema file from worksheet data](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/create-an-xml-data-file-and-xml-schema-file-from-worksheet-data-HA010263509.aspx)
- [MSDN Library: Creating an XML Mapping Schema in Excel 2010](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg469857(v=office.14).aspx)
- [Mr Excel: Using XML in Excel 2003](http://www.mrexcel.com/articles/using-xml-in-excel.php)

essentially you create a schema file then output the xml data using that schema to define the data.